# Generate model from database pg_hba entry

Tags: c#, entity-framework, postgresql

When I create ADO.NET Data Model and I try to generate model from database wizard gives me error no pg_hba entry for database template1.
I am providing database "X" in connection string which I have entry in ph_hba. I dont have acess to this database so i cannot ask for entry in pg_hba to database template1. How to deal with it ?

Comment: you need to explain more/....

Comment: When creating DataModel u need to provide ConnectionString to Database, clicking "Test Connection" gives me positive result. But when i click "Next" button i gives me error that i dont have entry in pg_hba for database tempalte1, whitch is correct cuz i have only access to database X not sure why generating model requires access to that database.